# Get Javascript Variable for Controller in Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I have javascript variable that contain latitude and longitude value, and i want to get that value for Controller in Laravel..

So i can use that value for calculate distance nearest location

Here's my javascript in my view:

```
<script>
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(setPosition);
        } else {
            alert('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
        }

    }

    function setPosition(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        console.log(longitude);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "HomeController.php",
            data: {
                'latitude': latitude,
                'longitude': longitude
            },
        });
    }
    console.log(latitude);
</script>
```

and here's my Controller:

```
        $latitude = JS_LATITUDE_VALUE;
        $longitude = JS_LONGITUDE_VALUE;

        $pharmacies = DB::table("pharmacies");

        $pharmacies = $pharmacies->select(DB::raw("id, pharmacy_name, pharmacy_address, pharmacy_thumbnail, pharmacy_excerpt, pharmacy_description, pharmacy_phone, pharmacy_wa, pharmacy_gmap, SQRT(POW(($latitude - pharmacy_lat ), 2) +
        POW(($longitude - pharmacy_long), 2)) * 111.319 AS
        distance"));
        $pharmacies = $pharmacies->having('distance', '<', 20);
        $pharmacies = $pharmacies->orderBy('distance', 'asc');

        $pharmacies = $pharmacies->paginate(3);

return view('pages.index', compact('pharmacies'));
```

Javascript value `latitude` and `longitude` from view is for fill variable in controller `$latitude` and `$longitude`

How do i get value from javascript parsing to Laravel controller as variable value?

Answer (score 0):

Inject the request in your Controller like that:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function myController(Request $request){ ... }
```

And get the results of your variable calling them from the Request like this:

```
$latitude = $request->latitude;
$longitude = $request->longitude;
```

Or you can use the request helper function if you don't want to inject the request in the Controller:

```
$latitude = request('latitude');
```

Comment: I try it, but still not getting the value that we request from javascript.. i dd($latitude) and the result is null.. it mean, we still not get javascript value for our controller method variable value.. any other way to get value from javascript variable?

Comment: check the request: `dd($request)`

Comment: Is the path of url: "HomeController.php", correct? I give the url HomeController.php because the javascript variable value is for HomeController

Comment: Ho boy, I did not see. The url is wrong in your ajax call

Comment: in your `web.php` routing file, name the route `->name('homeController')`. Then in your ajax url: `url: {{ route('homeController') }}`

Comment: You need to load the Laravel Application, you cannot pass `.php` in a url

Comment: I still dont get it, how do i make that? Sorry, i'm new at this..

Comment: Your Routes are in the files `routes/web.php`

Comment: check some tutorial about Laravel

Comment: I know the location of web.php, but i dont know how to make route for HomeController that will be call to ajax url.. Please help

Comment: What is your Laravel version? because it is diferent

Comment: Check here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding